# Kotlin: есть ли класс для подстроки?

Tags: строки, kotlin, substring, kotlin-faq

Есть рекурсивная функция принимающая на вход строку. Она разбивает эту строку на части и для каждой части вызывает саму себя. Эта функция никак не меняет входную строку, только читает её. Функция реализована на Kotlin.
Сейчас, для создания подстроки вызывается функция substring:

```
    myFunc(str.substring(begin, length))
```

Есть сомнения в эффективности данной реализации. На каждый вызов создаётся новая строка, хотя достаточно указать начало и длину подстроки в первоначальной строке.
Есть ли в Kotlin класс для подстрок? Например в стандартной библиотеке C++ есть класс [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), а в Qt есть класс [QStringRef](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringref.html). Есть ли что-то подобное в Kotlin?

Или класс String уже оптимизирован и функция substring не аллоцирует новую память, а новая строка использует тот же буфер в памяти, что и первоначальная?

Comment: Для удобства можете работать с `IntRange` и `fun String.substring(range: IntRange): String`

Answer (score 1):

В старых версиях java результатом `substring` действительно была исходная строка с указанием необходимого смещения.

Начиная где-то с 7 версии данное поведение было изменено и результатом `substring` теперь является новая строка.

В kotlin, как и в java, функция `substring` осуществляет копирование исходного массива байт с учётом необходимого смещения, т.е. создаётся новая строка, что можно наблюдать в исходниках, провалившись в метод `substring`.